# How to show average walking distance to closest point in census tract in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, distance, census

Given a map layer of point locations, and a second map layer of census tract polygons for the same area, how would you create a map layer that shows the average walking distance to the closest point for each census tract?

Euclidean distance?

Comment: Are you wanting to calculate the distance based on the centroids of the polygons, or the closest vertex along the polygon boundary, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the average walking distance to the closest point, you can indeed use the [Euclidian distance](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000001p000000) to create a raster of the distance to the closest point. Then you can compute the average distance using [zonal statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000w7000000) (or zonal statistics as a table if you prefer a vector output)

Comment: Would region group be needed to differentiate each census tract?

Answer (score 1):

Euclidean Distance and Zonal Statistics (As Table) will tell you the average distance to the closest point for each polygon.

It's worth considering that Euclidean distance is not *walking* distance. Walking routes are restricted: a person can't (reasonably) walk over a building, an interstate highway, a river/stream, etc.

A more accurate method would be to use [Network Analyst](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004700000001000000), but you would need to have a sidewalk/path shapefile for the area.

It is also possible to define "blocked" areas (buildings, waterways, etc.) and run an analysis with the [Cost Distance tools](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000018000000.htm), which are basically Euclidean Distance plus additional considerations -- but again, you'd need additional data.

**That being said**, Euclidean Distance can still be a useful *approximation*, particularly if you're interested in *relative* proximity to the point locations -- in other words, that Tract A is (on average) twice as far as Tract B.